# How do I allow communication between two Azure virtual networks with their own VPN gateways

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, tcpip, azure-networking

I need some help (or maybe a better angle of attack) connecting a few external users to our Azure tenancy.

*NOTE: All resources mentioned below are in the same Azure Subscription, the same Azure Location and the same Azure Resource Group.*

There's one virtual network with a Windows 2016 VM running. This v-net (call it **MAIN-VNET**) has a virtual gateway with a site-to-site VPN configured (call this **S2S-VPN**). This S2S VPN is configured as a policy-based IPSEC VPN so that the on-premise Billion 7800VDOX can connect - which it does without issue. But, because it's a policy-based configuration, I can't configure a point-to-site VPN in coexistence with this S2S. If it were route-based configuration however, P2S and S2S coexistence would work (and does - I tested it). But the on-premise Billion won't connect because it doesn't support IKEv2 (which is what route-based IPSEC VPN's use). So for now we're forced to use the policy-based config.

I have had to create a new v-net (**P2S-VNET**), then a new v-net gateway (**P2S-VPN**) and then configure the point-to-site VPN and client. I've done this and am able to connect to the VPN using the Azure VPN client successfully, but I can't access the Windows server on MAIN-VNET.

I can't create a "vnet-vnet" connection because one of the VPNs is policy-based and this is not supported by Azure.

I've tried creating a peer for both networks to each other (note that I have not ticked `Allow forwarded traffic`, `Allow gateway transit`, or `Use remote gateways` for either), but still cannot access the server.

I've created inbound/outbound rules in the network security group attached to the Windows server that allows ALL ports between the the various subnets each v-net has and this has not helped either.

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how I open traffic between the two v-nets?**  I need it so that any external users who connect through P2S-VPN can access the Windows server on MAIN-VNET.  Users on-premise who connect to this Windows server via the Billion device and the S2S VPN have no issues connecting to the Windows server at the moment.

```
LAN ==> Billion ==> S2S-VPN ==> MAIN-VNET ==> Windows server [OK]

Remote user ==> P2S-VPN ==> P2S-VNET =/= MAIN-VNET ==> Windows server [NOT OK]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you met the requirements for VNET Peering. All you have to do is connect both VNETs and enable Gateway Transit.

Here's an overview:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

And here's how to do it:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-vnetpeering-arm-portal

Just make sure to redownload the P2S client after reconfiguring VNET otherwise you won't have the new routes.

Comment: Hmmm...  I had already peered the two v-nets.  They have been "connected" for a day now.  I just tried recreating the VPN client, downloading it and connecting; it connects OK, but I cannot access the application our Windows server is running.
Is there any additional address spaces or subnets I need to have in each v-net?  Or something else I've missed?

Comment: Did you peered the vnets after or before configuring P2S? As I said, you need to redownload the client. You also have to make sure you've enabled Gateway transit during peering otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remote user ==> P2S-VPN ==> P2S-VNET =/= MAIN-VNET ==> Windows server [NOT OK]
```

It is a by design behavior, we **can't** use Vnet peering in this way(Vnet peering will not route your remote user's network traffic to windows server).

Your goal is to create P2S VPN between on-premise network and Azure Vnet(MAIN-VNET), as a workaround, we can create a windows server in MAIN-VNET, and configure it work as a **RRAS VPN** server, in this way we don't have to create another Vnet in Azure.

```
LAN ==> Billion ==> S2S-VPN ==> MAIN-VNET ==> Windows server 
Remote user ==> RRAS VPN ==>MAIN-VNET==>Windows server
```

Comment: That was my fall-back.  I can install RRAS/IIS on the Windows server being used by our application, but someone mentioned it would be vulnerable to a DDoS.  Would I be better to deploy a tiny Windows server instance in the MAIN-VNET and keep the RRAS dial-in SSTP VPN off the production server?

Comment: yes, I think deploy another VM in MAIN-VNET is better than install RRAS on your windows server 2016.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: RRAS is apparently not supported on Windows VM's in Azure - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines